# Applying AngularJS date filters with condition

Tags: angularjs, timeago

I just started with AngularJS and got stuck with a problem.

I have a date field to show in a grid.
Date format should be relative format like "1 day ago, 10 mins ago...."
So for that i used `timeAgo`, so it formats the date correctly.

But I have a requirement like:

> If the `last_updated_time` is less than 10 days, then show relative time like "1 day ago, 10 mins ago...."  else do not apply any filter.

Here is my code snippet.

```
<td data-title="'Last modified'" sortable="'last_updated_time'" align='center'>
    {{offer.last_updated_time | timeAgo }}
</td>
```

It would be great if someone can guide me how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function to get this:

```
$scope.getTimeAgo = function(last_updated_time ){
     var today = new Date();
     var days = today.diff(last_updated_time , 'days');
     if(days > 10)
        return last_updated_time;
     else
        return moment(last_updated_time).fromNow();
 };
```

then you can use it like follow:

```
{{getTimeAgo(offer.last_updated_time)}}
```

PS: I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for time ago but you can apply your time ago function into the else if you want to use your filter.

Comment: Hi nramirez, I apologize for the delayed reply... Thanks a ton for the answer... My requirement got changed slightly, so took another approach to solve... Thanks for your time.